# IBM Q calibration parameters

Tags: ibm-q-experience, error-correction, noise, decoherence

If I download calibration of a quantum processor on IBM Q website I see these parameters:

- T1
- T2
- frequency (GHz)
- readout error
- single qubit U2 error rate
- CNOT error rate

T1 and T2 are relaxation and dephasing times, respectively.

**What are the other parameters?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- frequency (GHz): The frequency(energy) associated with the transition between the qubit's ground state ($|0\rangle$) and first excited state ($|1\rangle$).
- readout error: The probability of preparing a $|0\rangle$($|1\rangle$) and measuring a $|1\rangle$($|0\rangle$), ie., of having an error in your readout
- single qubit U2 error rate: The average error per gate of a single qubit gate, this is $1 - \mathrm{average\_gate\_fidelity}$.
- CNOT error rate: The average error per gate of a two-qubit gate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by *average error*? Is it an average readout error? Or a probability that a gate will operate in wrong way? Lastly, I am a little bit lost in frequency - is it a frequency of photon that cause excitation from ground state to excited one?

Comment: - Average gate fidelity specifically means https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205035
- Yes, this is one way of thinking of the frequency but fundamentally it is related to the energy levels of the quantum system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_level